# Moore's function

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, mathematical-physics, quantum-gravity, casimir-effect

In the dynamical Casimir effect, the Casimir force is given in terms of Moore's function R which satisfies $$R(t+L(t))-R(t-L(t))=2$$ where $L(t)$ is the trajectory of a moving mirror (while another mirror is fixed at some position). My question is: can we solve for $R$ if $L(t)$ is given ? (it is actually a mathematical question)

Comment: At best we can solve for $R$ up to an additive constant. Does any condition remove that degree of freedom?

Comment: @J.G. you mean the solution will be something like R+constant ? if this is the case, I think we can do that because the casimir force actually depends on the derivatives of R. (is there any special name for this type of problems in mathmatics?, just to be able to look it up on the internet. thank you)

Comment: It’s a functional equation. Wegrzyn, P. (2007). Exact closed-form analytical solutions for vibrating cavities. Journal of Physics B: Atomic, Molecular and Optical Physics, 40(13), 2621.